# In CSS can I make an element only visible on a users profile when they are logged in and not when somebody else is viewing their profile?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

There is some text on my website which I have hidden using CSS. The text is "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." and is displayed on users profiles. Please see image below.

When I inspect it it looks like this:

https://prnt.sc/qskqbd

I have used the CSS:

```
#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard > p {
    display: none;
}
```

...which has hidden it but I would like it to be visible to the user whose profile it is on when they are logged in and only remain hidden when somebody else is viewing that users profile. 
I was just wandering if it was possible to modify this CSS code to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried anything through https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/ (on server side) ex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: @G-Cyr actually, at the moment the text in the question does only appear if a user is logged in. The problem I want to solve is that I only want the text visible if the user that is logged in is viewing their own profile and if somebody else who is logged in is viewing another persons profile then the text "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." should not be visible.